# asp.net mvc 5 t4 scaffolding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, templates, t4

I am using vs2013 and T4 Templates to generate the Views (Create, Edit, List)
what I need is to retrieve the Maxlength attribute .

Create.cs.t4 the file I have the following code ( snippet )

```
<#
foreach (PropertyMetadata property in ModelMetadata.Properties) {
  string inputlength = MaxLength(property);    
#>

    <#= property.PropertyName #> Maxlength is <#= inputlength  #>

<# } #>



string MaxLength(PropertyInfo property) {
    var stringLength = property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(StringLengthAttribute), false);
    if (stringLength != null && stringLength.Length > 0) {
        return ((StringLengthAttribute)stringLength[0]).MaximumLength.ToString();
    } else {
        return "0";
    }
}
```

I know I'm going PropertyMetadata instead of PropertyInfo , but this was the closest I could get , but it does not return me anything ..

Do not know if converting PropertyMetadata > PropertyInfo work , but do not know it .

My goal is to look at the properties that has MaxLength = 1

Note: the structure of templates is different from VS2013 VS2012, so I can not understand.

Comment: I have a very similar issue, have you happened to figure this out yet?

Comment: not yet, i try find the solution

Comment: Has anyone found a solution to this yet?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to reading the attributes in your MVC5 T4 templates is rather long, so I wrote a blog post about it here: https://johniekarr.wordpress.com/2015/05/16/mvc-5-t4-templates-and-view-model-property-attributes/